# Linux Command - Delete all non .svn files

Tags: linux, svn, delete-file

As the title says, how do I delete all the files inside a folder except the .svn folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o -name \* -delete
```

Tells find to start from the current directory, ignore all files (and directories) named .svn, and the rest, delete. To make sure it does the right thing before you delete, I'd recommend replacing the `-delete` flag with `-ls`.